# Keep getting:"Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'"?

Tags: android

I keep getting "Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'" I read some answers and they say you should use ListView list = getListView; Which I do and also I am using android:id="@android:id/list" for my list view yet my application keeps crashing when I try to have it open/launch an activity after each list view item is clicked?

```
<ListView
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="149dp"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    />


    ListView listView = getListView(); // hear bind your listview

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item,getResources()
            .getStringArray(R.array.countries)));


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View itemView, int itemPosition, long itemId)
        {
               //keeps crashing when trying to open Second activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Comment: "Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'" -- this is required if you inherit from `ListActivity` or `ListFragment` and you are supplying your own layout. "yet my application keeps crashing when I try to have it open/launch an activity after each list view item is clicked?" -- this has nothing to do with your previous complaint. Please post the entire stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: I got to work it was because my second activity class was extending the Main activity instead of just Activity. weird